# what is the trilinear coordinates of the intersection between these 2 circles

Tags: triangles, triangle-centres

(I really searched on the internet, I found NOTHING)

In a triangle, we can draw the 9-point Euler circle, and the 3 excircles of that triangle. there always is an intersection point between the Euler circle, add one of the 3 excicles (unique point).
I'd like to have the trilinear coordinates of these 3 points, because I searched everywhere in vain...

Comment: Please show us what you tried, it is the way it works. Or provide in some manner more / relevant context. Else not only the present question will be voted for closing, waiting for the same substantial context to be added, but also potential answers will be downvoted. This is always a frustration for all involved sides... And even the downvoters are not doing this gladly. (They have to come back, when things were changed...)

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeuerbachTriangle.html

Comment: Never knew that this stuff existed. Cool!